# Sample points from a hyperboloid

Tags: python, plot, random, data-generation

A hyperboloid has the formula

-x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 = 1.

How can I generate samples from this hyperboloid in Python? (Say, with a=b=c=1.)

I was thinking to pick random x and y in [0,1] and then fill in the z value that would make the formula equal 1. However this would not sample uniformly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a partial answer.

J.F. Williamson, "Random selection of points distributed on curved surfaces", *Physics in Medicine & Biology* 32(10), 1987, describes a general method of choosing a uniformly random point on a parametric surface. It is an acceptance/rejection method that accepts or rejects each candidate point depending on its stretch factor (norm-of-gradient). To use this method for a parametric surface, several things have to be known about the surface, namely—

- `x(u, v)`, `y(u, v)` and `z(u, v)`, which are functions that generate 3-dimensional coordinates from two dimensional coordinates `u` and `v`,
- The ranges of `u` and `v`,
- `g(point)`, the norm of the gradient ("stretch factor") at each point on the surface, and
- `gmax`, the maximum value of `g` for the entire surface.

The algorithm is then:

1. Generate a point on the surface, `xyz`.
2. If `g(xyz) >= RNDU01()*gmax`, where `RNDU01()` is a uniform random number in [0, 1), accept the point. Otherwise, repeat this process.

In the case of a hyperboloid with parameters a=b=c=1:

- The gradient is `[2*x, -2*y, 2*z]`.
- The maximum value of the gradient norm is:`2*sqrt(3)`, if `x`, `y`, and `z` are all in the interval [0, 1].

The only thing left is to turn the implicit formula into a parametric equation that is a function of two-dimensional coordinates `u` and `v`. I know this algorithm works for parametric surfaces, but I don't know if it still works if we "pick random x and y in [0,1] and then fill in the z value that would make the formula equal" in step 1.